# I cannot load the .js file and .css when using blade template in lavarel

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed my code as below

PHP 7, i user Lavarel framework 5x.

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('content')

      <h2>Test</h2>
@endsection

<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
                @yield('content')
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add some code here

Comment: Please don't post code as image, edit your question and add the code as text. [Why not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: thank!, i will........................

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the Support, i fixed it by editing the css link:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included css in head

```
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and js as the last in your body

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: When using mix function, I get an ErrorException (E_ERROR)
The Mix manifest does not exist.

Comment: is this a project you just started? do you plan on writing sass and then compile with mix or you are directly writing css in public/css? ```npm install``` and ```npm run dev``` could solve this problem but I don't know if that is what you want

Comment: If you dont mix up your files, Use `asset('js/app.js')` instead of `mix`